# Trailing <0x00> in SVG+XML file

Tags: java, xml, web, svg

Here is a screenshot of the XML file:

[image]

And when I open up the image in my browser, I get this error:

[image]

Has anyone faced a similar problem before?

Comment: Those zeroes should not be there. What is the program with which you created the file? Is it really "Adobe Illustrator"?

Comment: @zx485 the file is a form item that was received within a multipart/form-data POST request. The image content is then written to the local file system.

Comment: My guess is that whatever wrote the file just writes out the buffer with no respect to how full it actually was. I.e. whatever wrote the file is buggy.